# Drawing a partitioned set with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'd like to create a graphic of a set partitioned into subsets of various sizes/shapes/colors. (I'm trying to show a set partitioned by an equivalence relation into disjoint subsets, i.e., the equivalence classes).

I was hoping to find something on http://www.texample.net to give me an idea of a good method, but I'm having trouble finding any examples. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: If you only want a shape divided in some way, why not to draw a simple circle with radial cuts?

Comment: Related question (and nice answer) here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272806/drawing-abstract-region-with-partitions-using-tikz

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements to add colors are necessary.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \a in {20,60,120,180,230,250,310}
{
\draw (-1,.5) -- (\a:4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]