# Drawing abstract region with partitions using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, random-numbers, pgf-decorations

I want to draw an abstract region with five partitions, where each partition is shaded and labeled differently. An example region (without the shading) would be as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one basic option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and clipping and filling in the appropriate order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
  coordinate (aux0) at (0,1.5)
  coordinate (aux1) at (0,3.5)
  coordinate (aux2) at (10,3.5)
  coordinate (aux3) at (9,6)
  coordinate (aux4) at (4,0)
  coordinate (aux5) at (7,0)
  coordinate (aux6) at (2,6)
  coordinate (aux7) at (5,6)
  coordinate (esp1) at (0.2,2.5)
  coordinate (esp2) at (1.5,1.5)
  coordinate (esp3) at (3,0.1)
  coordinate (esp4) at (5.5,1.1)
  coordinate (esp5) at (8,0.5)
  coordinate (esp6) at (8.75,2)
  coordinate (esp7) at (9.7,3)
  coordinate (esp8) at (6.5,4.5)
  coordinate (esp9) at (3.8,5.8)
  coordinate (esp10) at (1.5,4)
  ;
\draw[line width=0.8pt]
  (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
  (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
  (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
  (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
  (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
  (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
  (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
  (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
  (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
  (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
  cycle;    
\clip
  (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
  (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
  (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
  (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
  (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
  (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
  (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
  (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
  (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
  (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
  cycle;    
\filldraw[fill=cyan!40]
  (aux4) to[bend right=10]
  (aux6) --
  (aux7) to[bend left=10]
  (aux5) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=brown!60]
  (aux5) to[bend right=10]
  (aux7) --
  (10,6) --
  (10,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!30]
  (aux0) -- 
  (aux1) to[bend right=10]
  (aux3) --
  (10,6) -- 
  (aux2) to[bend left=10] cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!50]
  (0,0) -- 
  (aux4) to[bend right=10]
  (aux6) --
  (0,6) -- 
  (0,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange!40]
  (0,6) -- 
  (aux1) to[bend right=10]
  (aux3) --
  (0,6) -- cycle;
\node at (4,5) {$E_1$};  
\node at (2,2) {$E_2$};  
\node at (6,3.3) {$E_3$};  
\node at (4.4,1.3) {$E_4$};  
\node at (7.5,2) {$E_5$};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]